# How would I create Horizontally centered “Gravity” ? - libGDX -

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d, game-physics

This is a seemingly simple game mechanic that I've been trying to figure out how to do.

***To try and explain I will describe a idea (problem):***

- Basically we say there's a vertical line that is centered in the
  screen.
- We have a sprite object that changes it's horizontal velocity to
  dodge missiles, however in doing that the object would just drift
  away.
- How can I add a strong gravity force to the horizontal "center line"
  of my screen so that my sprite will "fall" back into it every time it
  boosts its velocity outwards?

I could post my source code but it wouldn't be too helpful to solving the question in this particular situation.

I've searched around for days trying to figure this out so any help especially with code examples would be very helpful!

[image]

Comment: Maybe some descriptive images would help to understand your question. Also consider posting this question in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Please check out my edit, I have also posted this on gamedev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've programmed this type of thing in the past. Gravity (in physics) is an acceleration, so

1) if the sprite is to the right of the line you subtract from its horizontal velocity every 1/n seconds, and

2) if the sprite is to the left of the line you add to its horizontal velocity every 1/n seconds.

Experiment with adding/subtracting a constant, or with adding/subtracting a number that increases the farther the sprite is from the center line.

Either way you do it, that's going to create a pendulum effect. You'll also have to add a dampening factor if you don't want that.  One simple approach is that if the sprite is headed away from the center line, the value you add/subtract is larger than if the sprite is heading back towards the center line. So the "gravity" that pulls the sprite to a stop is greater than the gravitational acceleration that brings the sprite back to the center line.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I have one problem however, how would I create the center line variable? (I'm new to game development)

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and for marking my question as the right one! For the center line variable, I assume you'll know the X and Y positions of all your sprites.  Well let's say the screen is 800 pixels wide.  Any sprite with an X position of 400 is at the center line.  If the sprite's X is less than 400, then start adding your factor to its X velocity.  If the sprite's X is greater than 400, start subtracting your factor from its X velocity.  I think that should do it!

Comment: @BrettFromLA I upvoted your answer to. Just a little suggestion: You said, if the screen is 800 pixels wide a sprite with x coordinate 400 is on the center line. I would not raccomend you using pixels. Instead use camera to be resolution independent. Next thing: The sprites `x coordinate` is on its left, so if the sprite is exactly in the middle of the screen his `x coordinate` would be less then the gravity center, and he would move to the right. So you need to say: `if(sprite.x + sprite.width / 2  < gravityCenter)`. Anyways nice and detailed answer. +1

Comment: @Springrbua You're completely right! Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using libgdx you should also use camera. So you don't have to calculate verything in pixels. So for example you say my screen is 16 worldunits width and 9 world units height (16/9 aspect ratio). So you can say the center of gravity is in the center of that 16, so at 8.5 if i am not wrong. Now you can say: `if (player.center.x < 8.5f) { player.xSpeed += GRAVITY_HORIZONTAL }` and `if (player.center.x > 8.5) { player.xSpeed -= GRAVITY_HORIZONTAL }`. In this case the gravity is a constant value. But as @BrettFromLA said you can also let the value grow if the distance to the center grows.